# Downgrade my PHP version from ver. 5.3.8 to ver. 5.2 in XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am using **Apache 2.2.21** with **PHP 5.3.8** in my web development project in windows7 environment but the hosting management of the project can upgrade only to **PHP ver. 5.2**.

Is there a way to change php version inside XAMPP?

I just want to test if there are bugs appear if I use 5.2 php version.

Comment: that is insane! you should change your "hosting management"

Comment: yeah.. you're right.. and I knew it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). WampServer lets you install multiple versions of PHP, Apache and/or MySQL, and switch between them all via a menu option. ;)

Comment: Thanks Jelly! So I have to transfer my files and switch to WampServer if there is no way to replace that way.

Comment: my advice is to save the file and the dump of the database. Uninstall XAMPP. Install WampServer. Import your entire project with the WampServer and then develop the php version you prefer.

Comment: Thank you Jelly! But I know that there is difference between Xampp and WampServer that is why I'm asking that question so there is no big operation to do if possible. If Xampp has no feature for that then I have to start using Wamp. =)

Comment: here are the pros and cons between xampp and wampserver: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2171/wamp-vs-xampp-pros-cons-for-running-a-local-testing-server

Comment: Ok! I understand the pros and cons, but you need a software that allows you to make the switch between different versions of php. xampp does not allow it then I see no alternative.

Comment: Yeah! you are right Jelly. I google it already and found none for that xampp version. But I found that it's possible to install both at the same pc. Did you try it already?

Comment: No sorry! I have a Mac and i not use these software. I have installed and configured by hand, apache, php and mysql separately.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have to try it on my own. Maybe I'll test it to another computer so there are no conflicts happen. Thanks to you Jelly! =)

Comment: Try, if you have no conflict good for you otherwise install Wamp. Please set my answer as correct! thanks

Comment: Yeap I tried it already but it says "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" and I am new here. I'll vote it up if I have already enough reputation. Thanks.. you may vote up my question.. =D

Comment: I voted for your question. You can not vote, but you can accept the answer as the right one by clicking the check mark.